# Hide Information tab Panel in Mysql Workbench v8

Tags: mysql-workbench

is there any way to hide the table information subcolumn in mysql workbench?

I work with version 8.0

Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

Comment: No, so far I haven't found a way to do it.